# windows grep regex not working

Tags: regex, windows, git, grep

Windows 10.

grep installed as part of git installation.

```
>grep --version

grep (GNU grep) 2.27
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.

>git --version

git version 2.12.0.windows.1
```

**File sample.txt** created with notepad contains the following 3 lines;

```
a
b
c
```

Get grep to return lines starting with 'a' or 'c' ;

```
>grep ^[ac].*$ sample.txt
a
c
```

(OK - as expected)

Get grep to return lines starting with any char *except* 'a' or 'c' i.e. the line starting with 'b' ;

```
>grep ^[^ac].*$ sample.txt
a
c
```

why is this not working ?

Comment: The command line uses a caret to indicate an escape so must itself be escaped, try `^^` ?

Comment: Cheers ! post it as the answer and I'll accept it. ( used  ^^[^^ ... though "^[^ ... also works - double quotes ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the command line `^` is used to indicate an escape (i.e. `^|` is treated as as literal `|` as opposed to a command pipe).

To escape the escape double it so: `^^[^^ac ...`